# Update data in database with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, updates

Just want to check if it is possible to edit/update a data when my database is save the data like this:
[image]

I want to update the school_name, start_date, end_date, qualification_list all those but I don't know how. Previously I did an update and it was successfull but the style inside is different:
[image]

Can anyone give me any tips or what to do to be able to update the data for the first screenshot? Thanks in advance.

Previously I update my data like this:

```
public function update1(Request $request, $user_id){

    $object2 = qualification::find($user_id);
    $test = array();

$test['School'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);

$test['SDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
$test['EDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);
$test['qualification'] = implode(' , ', $request->qualification);
    $object2->update($test);
    return redirect('/home');

}
```

But how do I update the data now based on the first screenshot?

Comment: What is the primary key of the table? And can you get `$id` of the multiple rows? How to distinguish schools? By `user_id`?

Comment: I am using a one to many relationship where I have many schools and I use user_id to distinguish them(act as a foreign key). The $id is to get the user_id and the primary key is the id

Comment: Do you mean one user can have multiple schools?

Comment: Yup, if possible i want to do something like $test['meta_key = school_name'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);

Comment: `$object2 = qualification::find($id);` This line implies `$id` is `id` of the table, not the `user_id` ??

Comment: That is an old code, I just want to know how can I update the meta_value based on the first screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one user can have only one school and you can get `user_id`, the following code works.

```
public function update2(Request $request, $user_id){

    $rows = qualification::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        switch ($row['meta_key']){
            case 'school_name':
                $row['meta_value'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);
                break;
            case 'start_date':
                $row['meta_value'] = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
                break;
            case 'end_date':
                $row['meta_value'] = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);
                break;
            case 'qualification_list':
                $row['meta_value'] = implode(' , ', $request->qualification);
                break;
        }
        $row->save();
    }

    return redirect('/home');

}
```

Comment: It work, thanks a lot !! But could you explain to me what this case and switch thing is? It my first time seeing it

Comment: You're welcome. There's nothing special. The first line gets all rows of which `user_id` equals to the parameter. And for each row, according to the `meta_key`, appropriate `meta_value` is set and finally saved. That's all.